# Сохранить вычисленное поле в Базу Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Не могу сохранить значение вычисленного поля в базу данных. Есть 3 модели:

```
class ExchangeDirectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['curr_custom', 'type', 'commission', 'rate_custom', 'time_to_buy', 'available', 'new_rate', 'code_xml2']
    list_editable = ['commission', 'available']
    list_filter = ['available', 'crypto_curr', 'fiat_curr', 'type']
    search_fields = ['crypto_curr__title', 'fiat_curr__title']
    fieldsets = [
        ('Общая информация', {'fields': ['crypto_curr', 'fiat_curr', 'type']}),
        ('Параметры', {'fields': ['commission', 'time_to_buy', 'available']}),
    ]

    list_per_page = 10

    def curr_custom(self, obj):
        return obj.crypto_curr.title + "/" + obj.fiat_curr.title
    curr_custom.short_description = 'Направление'

    def rate_custom(self, obj):
        return str(convert(obj.crypto_curr.symbol, obj.fiat_curr.symbol, Decimal(1), 0, obj.commission, obj.type).result.__round__(obj.buy_curr.round))
    rate_custom.short_description = 'Курс обмена'

    def has_add_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

    def has_change_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

    def code_xml2(self, obj):
        crypto_xml = obj.crypto_curr.symbol_xml_crypto
        fiat_xml = obj.fiat_curr.symbol_xml_fiat
        code_xml2 = "{}{}".format(crypto_xml, fiat_xml)
        return code_xml2
    code_xml2.short_description = 'КОД пары XML'

class ExchangeDirection(models.Model):
    TYPES = ((ExchangeDirectionItems.BUY, ' Покупка крипты за фиат'), (ExchangeDirectionItems.SELL, ' Продажа крипты за фиат'))
    TYPES_DICT = {}
    for type in TYPES: TYPES_DICT[type[0]] = type[1]
    crypto_curr = models.ForeignKey(CryptoCurrency, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Криптовалюта")
    fiat_curr = models.ForeignKey(FiatCurrency, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Фиатная валюта")
    type = models.CharField('Тип', max_length=4, choices=TYPES)
    commission = models.DecimalField('Процент комиссии', default=1.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    time_to_buy = models.IntegerField('Время на оплату, с.', default=1200)
    available = models.BooleanField('Доступна')
    new_rate = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Курс с грамбита', default=0)
    code_xml = models.CharField('Код XML', max_length=4024)

    @property
    def sell_curr(self):
        return self.crypto_curr if self.type == ExchangeDirectionItems.SELL else self.fiat_curr

    @property
    def buy_curr(self):
        return self.crypto_curr if self.type == ExchangeDirectionItems.BUY else self.fiat_curr

    @property
    def get_code_xml(self):
        crypto_xml = CryptoCurrency.symbol_xml_crypto
        fiat_xml = FiatCurrency.symbol_xml_fiat
        code_xml = '{}{}'.format(crypto_xml, fiat_xml)
        return code_xml

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.code_xml = self.get_code_xml
        super(ExchangeDirection, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.crypto_curr}/{self.fiat_curr}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'направление обмена'
        verbose_name_plural = 'направления обмена'

class FiatCurrency(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=32)
    symbol = models.CharField('Символ', max_length=32)
    symbol_xml_fiat = models.CharField('Символ XML', max_length=1024, default='-')
    min_amount_buy = models.DecimalField('Мин. сумма покупки', default=1.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    max_amount_buy = models.DecimalField('Макс. сумма покупки', default=1.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    min_amount_sell = models.DecimalField('Мин. сумма продажи', default=1.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    max_amount_sell = models.DecimalField('Макс. сумма продажи', default=1.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
    wallets = models.TextField('Кошельки', max_length=512, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    wallets.help_text = "Через пробел или перенос строки."
    wallet_template = models.CharField('Шаблон кошелька', max_length=256, default='.+')
    wallet_example = models.CharField('Пример кошелька', max_length=256, default='-')
    symbol.help_text = "Пример: USD, BTC, ETH. Используется для получения курса через Binance API."
    wallet_template.help_text = "Регулярное выражение."
    symbol_xml_fiat.help_text = 'Код из XML файла выгрузки курсов обменника'

    @property
    def round(self):
        return 2

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'фиатная валюта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'фиатные валюты'

class CryptoCurrency(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=32)
    symbol = models.CharField('Символ', max_length=32)
    symbol_xml_crypto = models.CharField('Символ XML', max_length=32, default='')
    min_amount_buy = models.DecimalField('Мин. сумма покупки', default=1.0, decimal_places=50, max_digits=100)
    max_amount_buy = models.DecimalField('Макс. сумма покупки', default=1.0, decimal_places=50, max_digits=100)
    min_amount_sell = models.DecimalField('Мин. сумма продажи', default=1.0, decimal_places=50, max_digits=100)
    max_amount_sell = models.DecimalField('Макс. сумма продажи', default=1.0, decimal_places=50, max_digits=100)
    round = models.IntegerField('Знаков после зап.', default=2)
    wallets = models.TextField('Кошельки', max_length=512, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    wallets.help_text = "Через пробел или перенос строки."
    wallet_template = models.CharField('Шаблон кошелька', max_length=256, default='.+')
    wallet_example = models.CharField('Пример кошелька', max_length=256, default='-')
    symbol.help_text = "Пример: USD, BTC, ETH. Используется для получения курса через Binance API."
    symbol_xml_crypto.help_text = 'Код из XML файла выгрузки курсов обменника'
    wallet_template.help_text = "Регулярное выражение."

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'криптовалюта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'криптовалюты'
```

В admins.py модели зарегистрированы.

Необходимо сохранять, значения полей `code_xml`, каждого направления обмена в базу данных в таблицу `ExchangeDirection`, столбец `code_xml`
У меня сохраняется не значение этого поля а объект, в базе сохраняется строка: `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7fb638446220><django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7fb638446d00`

Comment: Исправил, но тогда выдается ошибка "'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Спасибо! Решил проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему!

```
    def get_code_xml(self):
    crypto_xml = self.crypto_curr.symbol_xml_crypto
    fiat_xml = self.fiat_curr.symbol_xml_fiat
    code_xml = '{}{}'.format(crypto_xml, fiat_xml)
    return code_xml
```